# Trouble finding inverse of CDF to sample from

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, statistics, sampling

I am attempting to do a discrete approximation using subintervals of a PDF's 99% CI. I understand that to generate samples from this distribution to use in my program, one can take the inverse of the distributions CDF and sample from that. The CDF I am attempting this on is:

$F(x) = 1-(3x+1)\exp -3x , \text{for} x \ge 0 $

Given the PDF, $f(x) = 9x\exp -3x , \text{for} x \ge 0$

Any help on how I can do this would be massively appreciated, I am struggling with the algebra. Further any help on an easier way to generate samples from this distribution would also be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\frac{1-F}{e}=(-3x-1)\exp(-3x-1)$, $x=-\frac{W(\frac{1-F}{e})+1}{3}$ where $W$ is the Lambert $W$ function. However, the easiest way to sample this distribution is to sum two $\lambda=3$ Exponential variables, as you can prove from moment generating functions (or, if you know enough about complex numbers to be more rigorous, characteristic functions).

Comment: I calculated the MGF of the distribution in the question to be: 9/(3-t), I don't fully understand how summing two exponential variables with MGF's respectively of 3/(3-t) would yield the result I am after.

Comment: @Natt-G You miscalculated; it's $9/(3-t)^2$.

Comment: Ah my mistake. So to sample now, I would generate two random numbers from the exponential distributions with rate = 3 and sum them together?

Comment: @Matt_G Yep, it's a standard technique with Erlang distributions, of which your problem is a special case.

Comment: Could i also just sample from a Gamma distribution with alpha = 2 and beta = 3?

Comment: @Matt_G You can use Gamma sampling if you know how to do that.